# How does CI leverages between using the controller or going to the real folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How does CI leverages between using the controller or going to the real folder?

If I have an URL: `http://localhost/sencha/touch/`

I have a controller method and folder with the same name (but no index file in it). My Apache server will give me the directory listing of the folder instead of going to the controller method (which would give me the proper index file).

***Some more context:***

I have a codeIgniter App and I have a sencha Touch application, an Ext JS application, some siesta tests.

a folder structure as following:

```
-application
   -config
   -controller
     -sencha.php
         methods: 
            touch()
            touch-siesta()
            ext()
            ext-siesta()
     -some_other_controllers...
   -model
   -view
      -template
      -some_other_views....
   -... other CI folders ...
-css
-js
-sencha
   -touch
       app            -> with the sencha mvc structure
   -touch-siesta      -> with the siesta stuff
   -ext
       app            -> with the sencha mvc structure
   -ext-siesta        -> with the siesta stuff
-system
-index.php
```

Following url all give me the directory listing instead of using the controller method.

```
http://localhost/sencha/touch/
http://localhost/sencha/touch-siesta/
http://localhost/sencha/ext/
http://localhost/sencha/ext-siesta/
```

**UPDATE:**

I had these lines in my rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I commented out the line where I check if it's a valid directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess` rule will treated first before other request by server, AFAIK CI is not deal with that yet, So, What you can do is either one of the following:

1. Dont use `Mod_rewrite`,
2. Edit `Mod_rewrite` rule e.g:

   ```
   RewriteRule /touch/(.*)$  /index.php/touch/$1
   ```

   But that is work for particular request only, not efficient.
3. Avoid name collision between folder and controller.

Comment: first one is not an option. third is ofcourse the goal. But I'll try number 2, not efficient but if it works... it's only for the 4 folders... I'll accept, after I tested it ;) Thanx!